# Mostrar datos manuales por pantalla, sin recogerlo de la base de datos

Tags: java, mysql, jsf

Estoy en un proyecto y tengo que hacer un filtro y mostrar por pantalla el resultado, el caso es este:

```
public List<StatisticCustomObject> getPrueba(Date fDesde,Date fHasta, List<Long> transito) {
    /*TypedQuery<StatisticCustomObject> typedQuery =  getEm().
            createNamedQuery("Mensaje.findPrueba", StatisticCustomObject.class);
    typedQuery.setParameter("fDesde", fDesde);
    typedQuery.setParameter("fHasta", fHasta);
    typedQuery.setParameter("Transito", transito);
    List<StatisticCustomObject> results = typedQuery.getResultList();

    return results;*/

}
```

Esto me devuelve el resultado por pantalla en una tabla (por el archivo en xhtml que tenemos creado), mi pregunta es como hago para devolver por pantalla manualmente, con los datos que yo quiera.

Saludos.

Comment: No se entiende mucho la pregunta pero lo que vas a tener que hacer es generar la lista de objetos `StatisticCustomObject` a mano y devolverla. El como rellenarla ya depende de la propia clase. Lo mejor para eso es usar la API. Ojo que puede que sea una interfaz y necesites usar una hija suya y sea bastante mas complicado.

Comment: @JDev Me refiero es que en vez de obtener datos de la base de datos y mostrarlo en pantalla, mostrar por ejemplo un número a mano, por ejemplo en ves de obtener una fecha ponerla a mano y se muestre

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solucionado mi problema, tan simple como lo siguiente:

```
List<StatisticCustomObject> results = new ArrayList<StatisticCustomObject>();
    StatisticCustomObject obj = new StatisticCustomObject(1L, 0, 0, null, null);
    results.add(obj);

    return results;
```